# Java - add a node to the end of a list?

Tags: java

Here's what I have:

```
public class Node{
    Object data;
    Node next;

    Node(Object data, Node next){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Object getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setData (Object data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next){
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

How do I write the code to add a Node at the end of a list?

So if I had

```
head -> [1] -> [2] -> null
```

How do I get to

```
head -> [1] -> [2] -> [3] -> null
```

Actually...I'm not even sure if I have to add to the end. I think it's valid to add and then sort? Not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify why you'd sort at all? Is the list supposed to be ordered by the data somehow? Plus, why the requirement to add to the end? (I know, I know, it's arbitrary, but I'm just trying to understand the entire question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void addToEnd(Object data){
    Node temp = this;
    while(temp.next!=null)temp=temp.next;
    temp.next=new Node(data, null);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `temp.next = new ...`?

Comment: Wouldn't `temp.next` always be null after the loop?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister yup, sorry. my mistake. Fixed now

Comment: This is correct; but I do think that a recursive algorithm would be more elegant here.  Not to mention that since this is homework, recursion was probably the whole point of the exercise.

Answer (score 4):

It's a linked list. You either have to

A) iterate through all your nodes starting at the head, find the last node, then add one.

or

B) keep track of the tail, add to the tail, then update tail to the new last node.

Answer (score 2):

Start from the head:

```
Node currentNode = headNode;
while (node.getNext() != null) {
   currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
}

currentNode.setNext(newNodeForInsertion);
```

A faster way is to store the last node of the list somewhere so you don't have to go through the whole list.

Answer (score 2):

Recursively navigate through each node until you hit the end.

```
public void navigate(Node insertNode)
{
    if(next == null)
        next = insertNode;
    else
        next.navigate(insertNode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the end, you'd have to walk to the end of the list (i.e., to where next=null) and add a new node there.

In the real world, you'd use an ArrayList for this and not bother with a linked list or manual structure at all.

Answer (score 1):

In your method to add a node, write a while loop that starts at the head and looks to see if the "next node" is null.  If it is not, advance to the "next node" and repeat.

Once you are at the node that points to nothing, adding the node is as simple as reassigning the null reference to the node to be added.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution:

```
public void addToEnd(Object data){
    if (next==null) 
      next = new Node(data, null);
    else
      next.addToEnd(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Node n = head;
while(n.getNext() != null){
    n = n.getNext();
}
n.setNext(nodeToAdd);
```

That's not sorted, which I can't tell from your question if you want it sorted.  Which opens up another whole can of worms such as what do you want to sort on,  if you have a linked list of type Object there isn't really anything meaningful to sort on.